# Why isn't the pause icon showing in JS

Tags: javascript, html, image, audio, video

When I click the play button the audio plays, the video plays, and when I click it again the video and audio stops just like it's supposed too. But for some reason, the play button doesn't change to the pause button when I click it. When it's showing the pause button it should return to the play button if I click it again.
Does anyone have a good solution for this?
Thanks, Love2Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Meditation App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            box-sizing:border-box;

        }
        .app{
            height:100vh;
            display:flex;
            justify-content:space-evenly;
            align-items:center;

        }
        .time-select,.sound-picker,.player-container{
            height:80%;
            flex:1;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction:column;
            justify-content:space-evenly;
            align-items:center;

        }
        .player-container{
            position:relative;
        }
        .player-container svg{
            position:absolute;
            height:50%;
            top:50%;
            left:50%;
            transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
            pointer-events:none;

        }

        .time-display{
            position:absolute;
            bottom:10%;
            color:white;
            font-size:50px;
        }
        video{
            position:fixed;
            top:0%;
            left:0%;
            width:100%;
            z-index:-10;

        }
        .time-select button, 
        .sound-picker button{
            color:white;
            width:30%;
            height:10%;
            background:none;
            border:2px solid white;
            cursor:pointer;
            border-radius:5px;
            font-size:20px;
            transition:all 0.5s ease;
        }
        .time-select button:hover{
            color:black;
            background:white;

        }
        .sound-picker button{
            border:none;
            height:120px;
            width:120px;
            border-radius:50%;
        }
        .sound-picker button:nth-child(1){
            background:#4972a1;
   

        }
        .sound-picker button:nth-child(2){
            background:#a14f49;
        }
  .sound-picker:focus{
  outline: none;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <div class="vid-container">
            <video Loop>
                <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/wkdu9elom9o4r5g/rain%20%281%29.mp4?raw=1"/>
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="time-select">
            <button data-time="120">2 Minutes</button>
            <button data-time="300">5 Minutes</button>
            <button data-time="600">10 Minutes</button>
        </div>
        <div class="player-container">
            <audio class="song">
                <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/jawlfpyyz83w2td/rain.mp3?raw=1"></source>
            </audio>
            <svg class="play"
            width="90" height="90" viewBox="0 0 68 78" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M68 39L0.499996 77.9711L0.5 0.0288552L68 39Z" fill="white"/>
        </svg>
        <svg class="track-outline"
        width="453" height="453" viewBox="0 0 453 453" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="226.5" cy="226.5" r="216.5" stroke="white" stroke-width="20"/>
    </svg>
    <svg class="moving-outline"
    width="453" height="453" viewBox="0 0 453 453" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="226.5" cy="226.5" r="216.5" stroke="#018EBA" stroke-width="20"/>
</svg>
<h3 class="time-display">0:00</h3>
</div>
<div class="sound-picker">
    <button data-sound="https://www.dropbox.com/s/jawlfpyyz83w2td/rain.mp3?raw=1" data-video="https://www.dropbox.com/s/wkdu9elom9o4r5g/rain%20%281%29.mp4?raw=1"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/8BspYTV/rain-1.png"></button>
    <button data-sound="https://www.dropbox.com/s/6k9nauf2ffyvfuu/beach.mp3?raw=1"
    data-video="https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsdd86bxmax32jp/beach.mp4?raw=1"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/T0xw4k7/sun-umbrella.png"></button>


</div>





</body>
<script>
  const app = () => {
        const song = document.querySelector(".song");
        const play = document.querySelector(".player-container");
        const outline = document.querySelector(".moving-outline circle");
        const video = document.querySelector(".vid-container video");

        //Sounds
        const sounds = document.querySelectorAll(".sound-picker button");
        //Time Display
        const timeDisplay = document.querySelector(".time-display");
        //Get length of the outside
        const outlineLength = outline.getTotalLength();
        //Duration
        let fakeDuration = 600;

        outline.style.strokeDasharray = outlineLength;
  outline.style.strokeDashoffset = outlineLength;
  
  //play sounds
  play.addEventListener("click", () => {
   checkPlaying(song);
  });
  //stop and play the sounds
  const checkPlaying = song =>{
    if(song.paused){
   song.play();
   video.play();
   play.src = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zvnjkebwt1sjgq/download%20%283%29.svg?raw=1';
  }else{
   song.pause();
   video.pause();
   play.src = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/8unx3knosmefedk/download%20%281%29.svg?raw=1';
  }
  }
    };  
    app();
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In here:

`const play = document.querySelector(".player-container");`

you are finding the div element, and then trying to assign a `src` property to it, naturally that won't work.

If you change your initial icon from:

```
<svg class="play"
            width="90" height="90" viewBox="0 0 68 78" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M68 39L0.499996 77.9711L0.5 0.0288552L68 39Z" fill="white"/>
```

**to**

`<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/8unx3knosmefedk/download%20%281%29.svg?raw=1" class="play" alt="">`

and then change the play query selector to: 
`const play = document.querySelector(".play");` it'll work.